# Dell inspiron N5050 8 beeps because "removed lcd cable"

Tags: dell, inspiron

I have recently remove the lcd cable. the beeps start from bios and when start up the sound still from speakers. when i boot to windows the beeps will disable. how can i disable it in ubuntu?

Comment: You can't - those beep codes are handled at the system firmware level and there is no way to override that part within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

What you're hearing is the system firmware on the Dell alerting you that there is something wrong with the system - in this case an LCD cable or other connection is missing and that indicates a problem in the system firmware level.

These are called Power On Self Test "Beep Codes" - they are handled at the system BIOS / firmware level, not Ubuntu, and you aren't going to be able to 'disable' those tests or the beeps from within Ubuntu.  You might be able to at the BIOS level but I'd be hesitant to guarantee that.

Comment: sure the sound at the bios level but i asked because when boot to windows the sound will stop after start up and i was wonder any way to stop it in ubuntu
the alsa process display :
 `0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 29`

Comment: @MOHD that's because the OS is booted and you've passed the POST, are you saying that in Ubuntu it doesn't stop?

Comment: yes i search any way to stop it after booted